# Determine ASP.NET Core environment name in the views

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, environment-variables

The new ASP.NET Core framework gives us ability to execute different html for different environments:

```
<environment names="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/material-design-lite/material.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</environment>
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-href="~/lib/material-design-lite/material.min.css"
          asp-fallback-test-class="hidden" asp-fallback-test-property="visibility" asp-fallback-test-value="hidden"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true"/>
</environment>
```

But **how can I determine and visualize the name of the current environment in the `_Layout.cshtml`** of an ASP.NET Core MVC web application?

For example I want to visualize the environment name (Production, Staging, Dev) as a HTML comment for debugging purposes:

```
<!-- Environment name: @......... -->
```

Answer (score 144, accepted):

You can inject the service `IHostingEnvironment` in your view by doing
 `@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment hostingEnv`
and do a `@hostingEnv.EnvironmentName`

Comment: Apparently in ASP.NET Core 3, it's @inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnv instead

Answer (score 25):

I just made a simple API controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class DebugController : Controller
{
    private IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnv;

    public DebugController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnv)
    {
        _hostingEnv = hostingEnv;
    }

    [HttpGet("environment")]
    public IActionResult Environment()
    {
        return Ok(_hostingEnv.EnvironmentName);
    }
```

Then I just run `/api/debug/environment` to see the value.

Comment: (this doesn't help with the views, but it's the quickest way I know of to check if my config is correct)

Comment: The answer belongs to the separate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56495475/asp-net-core-its-possible-to-configure-an-action-in-controller-only-in-developm

Answer (score 17):

Starting from .NET Core 3.1 it is recommended to use

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnv
```

Add this to at the top of your Razor view. You can use `@hostingEnv.EnvironmentName` to get the current environment.

Answer (score 16):

The following works In .net core 2.2:

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment env
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting 

if (env.IsProduction())
{
   //You can also use:

   //env.IsStaging();
   //env.IsDevelopment();
   //env.IsEnvironment("EnvironmentName");
}
```

Comment: You don't need `@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting`. Also your answer is the same as the one selected as best answer.

Comment: @NikolayKostov, you're wrong. To use the extension methods .IsProduction() and similar, then you must use using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting. 

My answer is different because the best answer is no longer valid in .net core 2.2. I suggest you test the best answer and my answer under .net core 2.2 before you say anything.

Comment: For me your approach did not work in .net core 2.2 I had to use @env. otherwise I was getting env is not defined
`if (@env.IsProduction()){}`

Comment: @Jules you need to add the above two lines of inject and using

Comment: @Shadi What I wanted to say is that you simply need to change env.IsProduction() to @env.IsProduction(), while leaving the rest of the code unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

Just to build on @Simon's answer

`IHostEnvironment` will become obsolete

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment?view=aspnetcore-7.0

You can use `IWebHostEnvironment` instead.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class DebugController : Controller
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostingEnv;

    public DebugController(IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnv)
    {
        _hostingEnv = hostingEnv;
    }

    [HttpGet("environment")]
    public IActionResult Environment()
    {
        return Ok(_hostingEnv.EnvironmentName);
    }
}
```