# ASP.NET core it's possible to configure an action in controller only in development mode?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my ASP.NET core web application, I want to have an action that runs only in development mode. In production mode, maybe a 404 error will be good enough. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This can be achieved by injecting `IHostEnvironment` into your controller and using its `IsDevelopment()` method inside of the action itself. Here's a complete example that returns a 404 when running in anything other than the Development environment:

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHostEnvironment hostEnvironment;

    public SomeController(IHostEnvironment hostEnvironment)
    {
        this.hostEnvironment = hostEnvironment;
    }

    public IActionResult SomeAction()
    {
        if (!hostEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
            return NotFound();

        // Otherwise, return something else for Development.
    }
}
```

If you want to apply this more globally or perhaps you just want to separate out the concerns, Daboul explains how to do so with an action filter in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56495597/2630078).

---

For ASP.NET Core < 3.0, use `IHostingEnvironment` in place of `IHostEnvironment`.

Comment: on .NET Core 6.0 LTS, it's deprecated and changed to `IWebHostEnvironment` look into https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iwebhostenvironment?view=aspnetcore-6.0 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment?view=aspnetcore-6.0 (deprecated)

Answer (score 25):

One nice way to do it is to create a `DevOnlyActionFilter` filter https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2

The filter would look like that:

```
public class DevOnlyActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private IHostingEnvironment HostingEnv { get; }
    public DevOnlyActionFilter(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnv)
    {
        HostingEnv = hostingEnv;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if(!HostingEnv.IsDevelopment())
        {
            context.Result = new NotFoundResult();
            return;
        }    

        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

And to annotate your controller action with     `[TypeFilter(typeof(DevOnlyActionFilter))]`

Answer (score 12):

[@Daboul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56495597/1511092) is pretty good but I didn't like the `TypeFilter(typeof(x))` which feels clunky.

Turns out that implementing `IFilterFactory` allows for attribute filters to have DI while still being clean to use.

```cs
public class DevOnlyAttribute : Attribute, IFilterFactory
{
    public IFilterMetadata CreateInstance(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return new DevOnlyAttributeImpl(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IWebHostEnvironment>());
    }

    public bool IsReusable => true;

    private class DevOnlyAttributeImpl : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public DevOnlyAttributeImpl(IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnv)
        {
            HostingEnv = hostingEnv;
        }

        private IWebHostEnvironment HostingEnv { get; }

        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            if (!HostingEnv.IsDevelopment())
            {
                context.Result = new NotFoundResult();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the controller/action can be annotated with `[DevOnly]`.

Comment: Awesome – three good answers to the question, building on each other. That's what Stack Exchange is all about. Thank you Kirk Larkin, Daboul and elexis! This combination of `Attribute`and `IFilterFactory` is really clean and I'm sure I'll be able to reuse it in other contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that might be appropriate in some cases, is to completely ignore compilation of some action, or the entire controller class even, in '*DEBUG*' mode.

For this, you can use C# compile directives:

```
#if DEBUG
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    // your actions..
}
#endif
```