# ASP endpoint only in development

Tags: asp.net-core, controller, development-environment

Is it possible (and preferably clean and easy) to set up ASP .Net Core controllers that are only accessible when running in specific `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`s? For example could I have an endpoint to simplify the testing of a specific bit of functionality (in a more integration over unit test manner) that is only available when running in a `Development` environment, and raises the usual 404/other errors in a `Production` environment?

Comment: Does this help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56495475/asp-net-core-its-possible-to-configure-an-action-in-controller-only-in-developm/56495545#56495545

Comment: Yes, that appears to be about what I'm after, particularly the second option of adding an attribute to the methods. My google-fu apparently wasn't up to snuff.

Comment: Yeah, the filter approach is the better option from a re-usability perspective.