# Mvc routing. How can i set a default parameter in .net core 3.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

My controller is

```
public partial class GridController : Controller
{
      [Route("/grid/{name}")]
      public IActionResult Index(string name)
      {

      }
}
```

Routing is setup correctly since if i visit `/grid/something` i get http ok.

But how can i set a default parameter in startup.cs?

I tried the following but on page load, i get http 404 error

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                   "default",
                   "{controller=Grid}/{action=Index}/{name}");
```

Comment: I tried specifying an argument for the parameter, e.g. `.../{name=something}`, but I still got routed to the parameterless action. I'm almost sure this used to work, but ended up using your workaround.

Comment: Turns out it does actually work, but only when the action has only a single overload and no `RouteAttribute`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. Ended up with a workaround

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    "default",
    "{controller=Grid}/{action=Index}");
```

and by adding an extra action overload.

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return Index("something");
}
```

it simply works

```
[Route("/grid/{name}")]
public IActionResult Index(string name )
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your route template. The `name` parameter is not optional.

So, use `{name?}`.

Comment: I have set both "optional parameter" and "name?" but the issue persists. I have seen that MapControllerRoute has an overload "object defaults" but i have not find any additional info yet

Comment: Try to remove the Route Attribute on the Index action. Should work.

Comment: Actually i am not looking for something like that. I wish to have the Route attribute. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: It's okay. But on page load, your application will try to find /Grid/Index. Your current decoration will map to /Grid/name. There is obviously a difference. Unless I don't understand what you want.

Comment: Your comment was great. Thanks! It initiated a workaround

Answer (score 0):

Use attribute routing at Controller level, So that it will be applicable to all the action method under that controller.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you did not specify the `name` parameter in your endpoint configuration. So it should have been `{controller=Grid}/{action=Index}/{name=something}`. But if there are overloads, this does not seem to work anyway. I wonder if this is a bug or is it intended by design. It seems that if there is are multiple overloads of the same action, execution gets directed to the parameterless one.

Here's another workaround with the possibility to use parameters. I tried this with .NET Core 2.2. Create a new action with the same parameters, but without `RouteAttribute`. From there you can do a redirect to the necessary action. Here's an example where I use `TestIndex` for the default route.

```
[Route("/[controller]/{name}/{age}")]
public IActionResult Index(string name, int age)
{
    // implementation
    return Ok($"{name} is {age} years old.");
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
    return Index("Mr. It", 7);
}

public IActionResult TestIndex(string name, int age)
{
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index), new { name, age });
}
```

Then for default route use the new method, e.g. `{controller=Grid}/{action=TestIndex}/{name=That}/{age=42}`.

If you use this for testing, the new action could be omitted from production by adding a `TypeFilterAttribute`. See [this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56495597/5050045).